# KeywordQuery problem

Tags: 2010, keywordquery

Can anyone help me with SharePoint 2010 KeywordQuery problem?
I have the following code to search user profile and sort results by managed property.

```
var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(site)
{
    QueryText = "",
    KeywordInclusion = KeywordInclusion.AllKeywords,
    HiddenConstraints = "scope:" + "\"People\"",
    ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults,
    RankingModelId = "D9BFB1A1-9036-4627-83B2-BBD9983AC8A1"
};

keywordQuery.EnablePhonetic = true;
keywordQuery.EnableNicknames = true;
keywordQuery.ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.SharepointSearch;

keywordQuery.SortList.Add("WorkEmail", SortDirection.Ascending);

keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("PreferredName");
keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("AccountName");
keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("OrganizationDepartment");
keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("UserFirstName");
keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("UserLastName");
keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("UserSurName");

ResultTableCollection resultTableCol = keywordQuery.Execute();
ResultTable resultTable = resultTableCol[ResultType.RelevantResults];
```

When I use `WorkEmail` as the property to sort by everything is working as  expected.

But when I replace `WorkEmail` with say `JobTitle` sorting does not work. It behaves as if the sort list passed to KeywordQuery is empty.

My view is that something wrong with managed properties metadata. `MaxCharactersInPropertyStoreIndex` is set to 64 for both mentioned properties.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a delayed reply on this but this might help someone else - even with SharePoint 2013.

If you recently changed the `MaxCharactersInPropertyStoreIndex` property of a managed property you'll most likely have to do a full crawl of the content source before it will take effect and be sortable.